Understanding 連れていかれそう
In this panel, a guy is talking about how having a girlfriend is impossible and his friends agree.

I might be overthinking but I am uncertain with 初デートでアニメイト連れていかれそう part, especially the use of passive verb 連れていかれる. I initially thought the subject of the verb 連れていかれそう is a girl he takes for date. But after reading lines 記念日にファミレス連れてってフラれそう and 財市マジックテープそう, which obviously takes the guy in question as the subject, I am tempted to think the actual subject for 連れていかれそう should be the guy himself.

Assuming only the guy is an otaku:

初デートでアニメイト連れていかれそう: the subject is the girl
記念日にファミレス連れてってフラれそう: the subject is the guy
財布マジックテープそう: this is about the guy's wallet

Native speakers wouldn't even notice the subject has changed between the first and the second sentences.

He is concerned that he will be taken (連れて行かれる) to Animate by the girl.
And that he will be dumped (フラれる) when he takes her (連れて行って) to the fami-res.
財布マジックテープそう is not grammatical, and is probably just a joking play on the series of sentences ending in そう.
